# Show combo on AspxGridview

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, devexpress

I work on `northwind` database. In my `AspxGridview` I want to show `comboBox`. I fill grid on back end `C#` I also want my combo will fill back end.

```
 <dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="CategoryID" 
            oncelleditorinitialize="ASPxGridView1_CellEditorInitialize">
            <Columns>
                <dxwgv:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0" Width="80px">
                    <EditButton Visible="True">
                    </EditButton>
                    <NewButton Visible="True">
                    </NewButton>
                    <DeleteButton Visible="True">
                    </DeleteButton>
                </dxwgv:GridViewCommandColumn>
                <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="CategoryID" FieldName="CategoryID" 
                    VisibleIndex="1">
                </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dxwgv:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn Caption="CategoryName" 
                    FieldName="CategoryName" VisibleIndex="2">
                    <PropertiesComboBox TextField="Value" ValueField="key" ValueType="System.Int32">
                        <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e) { OnBankChanged(s); }" />
                    </PropertiesComboBox>
                </dxwgv:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
                <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Description" FieldName="Description" 
                    VisibleIndex="3">
                </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            </Columns>
        </dxwgv:ASPxGridView>
```

**To fill grid i use the bellow C# syntax.**

```
  DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var r = from p in db.Categories
                    select p;
            ASPxGridView1.DataSource = r;
            ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
```

**To fill gridview cell of combo i use Bellow C# syntax**

```
 protected void ASPxGridView1_CellEditorInitialize(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewEditorEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!ASPxGridView1.IsEditing || e.Column.FieldName != "CategoryID") return;
            ASPxComboBox combo = e.Editor as ASPxComboBox;

            if (!(e.KeyValue == DBNull.Value || e.KeyValue == null)) //return;
            {
                object val = ASPxGridView1.GetRowValuesByKeyValue(e.KeyValue, "CategoryID");
                if (val == DBNull.Value) return;
                Int32 CategoryID = (Int32)val;
                FillCityCombo(combo, CategoryID);
            }

            combo.Callback += new CallbackEventHandlerBase(cmbBranch_OnCallback);

        }

        private void cmbBranch_OnCallback(object source, CallbackEventArgsBase e)
        {
            FillCityCombo(source as ASPxComboBox, Convert.ToInt16(e.Parameter));
        }

        protected void FillCityCombo(ASPxComboBox cmb, Int32 CategoryID)
        {
            //cmb.Items.Clear();
            //cmb.DataSourceID = "";
            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var r = from p in db.Categories
                    select new { p.CategoryID,p.CategoryName};
            cmb.DataSource = r;
            cmb.DataBind();
        }
```

When I run the code `AspxGridview` fill well but when I click on Edit or New Command on left side of my grid shows me error message below:

```
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
```

1. What's the problem?
2. How to solve this problem?
3. How to bind cell combo on aspx gridview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the cause of this issue.  You are checking for the "CategoryID" field name.  But the ComboBox column is created for the "CategoryName" field:

```
if (!ASPxGridView1.IsEditing || e.Column.FieldName != "CategoryID") return;
ASPxComboBox combo = e.Editor as ASPxComboBox;
```

Comment: thanks it's really a big mistake.thaks.This problem is solve but when i click on New command link of AspxGridview my combo is not load .will you please tell me the reason?Thanks again

Comment: click on new command why this method is not active
 private void cmbBranch_OnCallback(object source, CallbackEventArgsBase e)
        {
            FillCityCombo(source as ASPxComboBox, Convert.ToInt16(e.Parameter));
        }

Comment: Why my OnCallback event is not active.How to active on this event.plz see my above syntax.

Answer (score 1):

We've posted a sample project showing how to implement dependent combos in insert mode at:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q102130

I hope, this project will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Bind in the OnRowDataBound event (or AspxGridview equivalent)

Comment: will you plz send some syntax how to Bound data on AspxGridView for cell combo